# What was defined in unicode-math to occur that?

Tags: unicode-math

Initial code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
:$\overline {\mathit v}$:
\end{document}
```

[image]

Use **unicode-math** package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO, mathbf=sym]{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
:$\overline {\mathit v}$:
\end{document}
```

[image]

Patch code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO, mathbf=sym]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\begin{document}
:$\overline {v}$:


:$\overline {\mathit{v}}$:
\end{document}
```

Comment: [xelatex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfiVz.png) but [lualatex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uA6I.png) so it seems to be a feature of xetex rather than `unicode-math`

Comment: why do you use \mathit and so switch to a text font?

Comment: why are you using `\mathit v` at all? The syntax should be `\mathit{v}` but using `\mathit` for single letters is quite rare why not simply `v` so it uses math italic?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry ,i explain that use **unicode-math** package to define math font, but not in example code.I submit patched code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Patched code is submitted.I want to use italic shape adjusted by `\mathit`

Comment: @Mahsatshak why don't you want to use the math italic that you have specified (TeX Gyre Termes Math) ?